# While loop runs forever in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've writen a function in JavaScript that checks through all the combinations of three digits between 1 and 9 and gives me the number of combinations that follow this pattern
√(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = a natural number (a full number like 24 or 34 but not 2.54)

√ = square root , ^2 = to the power of 2,

My problem is that whenever I run the function the computer gets stuck and the function never ends so it doesn't return an answer.
I would very much appreciate if someone could tell me whats wrong with it 
(I'm running my programs on the chrome browser console)

```
function mmd() {
    var chk = false;
    var a = 1;
    var b = 1;
    var c = 1; 
    var d = 1;
    var e = 0;
    while(chk != true) {
        d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2)+Math.pow(b, 2)+Math.pow(c, 2));
        if( d == d.toFixed(0)) {
            e++;
        }
        else {
            if((b == 9) && (a == 9) && (c == 9)) {chk = true;}
            else if((a == 9) && (b == 9)) {c++;}
            else if(b == 9) {b = 1; a++;}
            else if(c == 9) {c = 1; b++;}
            else if(c < 9) {c++;}
        }
    }
    return e
}
```

Comment: you only change the `check` if all the numbers equal 9 but you keep changing `b` and `c` back to 1 over and over

Comment: if `(d == d.toFixed(0))`, you do `e++;` and nothing else. If this condition is met even once, it will always stay true, and your loop will keep doing `e++` for ever (well, until it crashes).

Comment: Isn't this off topic? I'd suggest using the code review stack exchange website.

Comment: @evolutionxbox If it's broken, it's for Stack Overflow. If it's not, but needs quality check, performance etc., *then* it's for Code Review.

Comment: Side note: There's no reason to use a runnable snippet for code that doesn't run. (You should include your code but it may confuse people that you're hiding the actual code and that the snippet doesn't produce results.)

Answer (score 3):

This part of the code is causing it to never end:

```
if (d == d.toFixed(0)){} else {}
```

If the result of the formula is an integer, you add 1 to `e`, but you don't increment the other variables, because of the `else`. It keeps doing `e++` for ever. So you need to remove that `else`.

I also took the liberty or removing that `chk` variable, and instead used `while(true)`, which will be ended by a return of the final result:

```js
function mmd() {
    var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d, e = 0;

    while(true) {
        d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2)+Math.pow(b, 2)+Math.pow(c, 2));
        if( d == parseInt(d, 10)) {
            e++;
        }

        if((b == 9) && (a == 9) && (c == 9)) {return e;}
        else if((a == 9) && (b == 9)) {c++;}
        else if(b == 9) {b = 1; a++;}
        else if(c == 9) {c = 1; b++;}
        else {c++;}
    }
}

alert(mmd());
```

Comment: up voted. Yet, might there be a more elegant test than: d == d.toFixed(0) ?

Comment: @Roberto Thank you, I've now replaced it with `parseInt`, which does seem more natural to me, but I don't have any argument for it being better than `toFixed()`.

Answer (score 0):

It gets stuck once it hits the `e++` block and never increases `a`, `b`, or `c`.

```
function mmd()
{
    var keepGoing = true;
    var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d, e = 0;
    while(keepGoing)
    {
        // calculate d
        d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2));

        // check if it is a whole number
        if(d == d.toFixed(0)) e++;

        // if we're done then stop
        if(a == 9 && b == 9 && c == 9){ keepGoing = false; }

        // if c is less than 9 then increase it
        else if(c < 9){ c++; }

        // if c is 9 and b is less than 9 then set c back to 1 and increase b
        else if(b < 9){ c = 1; b++; }

        // if c is 9 and b is 9 then set both back to 1 and increase a
        else if(a < 9){ c = b = 1; a++; }
    }
    return e;
}
```